# Carrier concentration decreasing with increase in temperature in a semiconductor

Tags: semiconductors

I have come across this equation in my semiconductor study $$
n_{0}=n_{i} \exp \left(\frac{E_{F}-E_{i}}{K{T}}\right)
$$ where$$n_i$$ is the intrinsic electron concentration .  This equation  gives us the electron concentration as a function of temperature.
But this equation suggests that as we increase the temperature, the conduction electron density decreases which is contrary to the fact that as we increase the temperature more and more electrons jump into the conduction band and hence increase in carrier concentration.
Where am I going wrong,please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you define the terms; especially \$n_0\$ and \$n_i\$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forgetting that `n_i` depends on T as well, you can find it's formula by googling it easly, also remember that this equation is approximation for when `E_f` close enough to `E_i` (and then you can drop the 1 at the denominator of the fermi functionn)

Comment: Thank you a lot.